# Job spec wraps error with Minitest::UnexpectedError after Rails 6.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

After upgrading to Rails 6.1, a test is broken:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  class MyError < StandardError; end

  def perform
    raise MyError
  end
end

describe MyJob, type: :job do
  it "throws an error" do
    expect do
      perform_enqueued_jobs { MyJob.perform_later }
    end.to raise_error(described_class::MyError)
  end
end
```

This spec fails with the error

```
expected MyJob::MyError, got #<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception> with backtrace:
```

When looking closer what error is thrown, it looks like this:

```
    69:
    70: describe MyJob, type: :job do
    71:   it "throws an error" do
    72:     expect do
    73:       binding.pry
 => 74:       perform_enqueued_jobs { MyJob.perform_later }
    75:     end.to raise_error(described_class::MyError)
    76:   end
    77: end

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyJob>)> perform_enqueued_jobs { MyJob.perform_later }
Minitest::UnexpectedError: MyJob::MyError: MyJob::MyError
    /usr/src/app/spec/lib/my_job_spec.rb:5:in `perform'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-6.1.6/lib/active_job/execution.rb:48:in `block in perform_now'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/airbrake-13.0.0/lib/airbrake/rails/active_job.rb:22:in `block in perform'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/airbrake-ruby-6.1.0/lib/airbrake-ruby/benchmark.rb:13:in `measure'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/airbrake-13.0.0/lib/airbrake/rails/active_job.rb:21:in `perform'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/airbrake-13.0.0/lib/airbrake/rails/active_job.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ActiveJob>'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
```

It seems like the error is somehow wrapped with `Minitest::UnexpectedError`, but the original underlying error is still there.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[These](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38749) changes were made in Rails 6.1 with `perform_enqueued_jobs`

So to fix your test you need to rewrite it like shown below:

```rb
describe MyJob do
  it "throws an error" do
    expect do
      described_class.perform_later
      perform_enqueued_jobs
    end.to raise_error(described_class::MyError)
  end
end
```